# task scheduler run whether user is logged or not could not working

Tags: scheduler

I have trouble in making a task scheduler to copy file from server(where the task located) to another server.
I write a bat file with content as below

```
net use \\teams
copy "\\xxxxxxxxxx\ChinaDA\ILS\BJCAE.xlsx" "\\yyyyy\ChinaDA\Courtesy Call\ILS\copy"
copy "\\xxxxxxxxxx\ChinaDA\ILS\SHCAE.xlsx" "\\yyyyy\ChinaDA\Courtesy Call\ILS\copy"
copy "\\xxxxxxxxxx\ChinaDA\ILS\SZCAE.xlsx" "\\yyyyy\ChinaDA\Courtesy Call\ILS\copy"
copy "\\xxxxxxxxxx\ChinaDA\ILS\BJFDX.xlsx" "\\yyyyy\ChinaDA\Courtesy Call\ILS\copy"
copy "\\xxxxxxxxxx\ChinaDA\ILS\SHFDX.xlsx" "\\yyyyy\ChinaDA\Courtesy Call\ILS\copy"
copy "\\xxxxxxxxxx\ChinaDA\ILS\SZFDX.xlsx" "\\yyyyy\ChinaDA\Courtesy Call\ILS\copy"
net use \\teams delete
```

and what I confuse is that when I log on the server the task can run perfectly or when I shut down my PC and set the trigger time at 12:30 pm it also can run perfectly. 
But when I set the trigger time at 6:10 am(My work time is between 9:00 am to 6:00 pm) it returns "the operation completed successfully(0x0)" but it do nothing to copy file!

Comment: Is the scheduled task running on your PC?  Are you actually shutting your PC down or just logging off?

Comment: No,the scheduled task is running on a server , I use remote desktop connection to set the task on the server. And I disconnected to the server and shut down my own PC during lunch time , the task can run and it give me a result expected

Comment: Does the user that the scheduled task run under have permissions to run as a service?

Comment: I connect to the server by domain\username and the administrator has granted my account permissions as administrator. And what more strange there is a task running under administrator fail either !The server is Win7 version not classical windows server

Comment: The issue could be that when you aren't logged in, the user account needs special permission to run as a service.

Comment: so what should I do now !

Comment: Is there any expert to help me ?